# I have a canon 7d Markii, how to set insignia remote

Tags: canon

I have a canon 7D markii and I am trying to set up the remote shutter control.  It is an insignia NS-WSCC.  It says to set my camera to IR mode, but can not find instructions on how to do that in my manual.  Can you help?

Answer (score 1):

Pages 248-9 of the [7D Mark II Instruction Manual](http://gdlp01.c-wss.com/gds/5/0300016615/01/eos7d-mk2-im-en.pdf#page=1&zoom=page-fit,-306,402) cover how to use a compatible infrared remote with your camera.

To set the *Drive Mode* to one of  the remote modes:

- Press the *Drive-AF* button on the top of the camera, just in front of the top LCD panel.
- Rotate the large *Quick Control Dial* on the back of the camera until the timer symbol (looks like a small flashlight and a stopwatch) appears in the viewfinder and in the lower left corner of the LCD panel.
- If there is no number next to the timer the camera will operate when you press the button on the remote. (Please note that the same symbol is used for a 10 second delay when using the camera's built-in shutter button).
- If there is a "2" displayed with the timer symbol, the camera will wait 2 seconds before operating after you press the remote button.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is to set the "Drive Mode" to one of the self-timer/remote settings. Either the 2-second or 10-second timer modes will work. In these modes, when you point a compatible infrared remote at the front of the camera, the shutter release button on the remote will immediately trigger the shutter on the camera.

Check the page on "Remote Control Shooting" in your 7D manual. In the original 7D manual it's page 114 in chapter 5, "Advanced Operations," but of course it might be a little different in the 7D Mk II manual.